# JqueryMobile - My Page Appears Before transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am setting up an app with JqueryMobile. Whenever I click on my navigation the next page appears on top of the current page for a second and then disappears and then the transition starts and the next page appears. Is this a known problem that anyone else is having and if so, how can I fix it. I know there's an issue with flashing transitions but I don't think this is the same. I'm using un-altered jquerymobile docs. Below is my code:

https://gist.github.com/2401211

Comment: It would be much more helpful to post your code in a JSFiddle so we can see the output and play with the code.

Comment: For everyone looking for answers...solution = Don't use transitions. Hoping transitions are fixed in a major for the next iteration of jquerymobile.

Comment: You never said what device you're running, what OS it had, and you're using an old version of jQuery Mobile. For instance, if you are running an iPhone with older than iOS 5 then your PhoneGap app. won't get to use the Nitro JS Engine and your app. will run about half as fast as in the Safari Browser. If you update to the new version of jQuery Mobile (1.1.0 Final) then only devices that can handle a transition will get to use it, everyone else gets a simple `fade` transition.

Comment: This isn't a matter of the device not running up to speed. I'm running on ios5 jqm 1.1.0, the files listed in my code are labelled incorrectly (I've been testing different versions). The transition isn't lagging, it's showing the page before it transitions. Something is wrong with the code, not the speed of the render.

Comment: I'll suggest again that you create a JSFiddle of the issue, basically re-create the issue so people can help you fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your complaint/issue is a common one. The transitions can be especially hideous on an android 2.x devices. Here is a quote form their blog

> We did a ton of work leading up to 1.0 to make our transitions as
>   smooth as possible, but there were two significant things that turned
>   out to very difficult: the need to scroll the page between transitions
>   and Android’s poor animation performance. [Source](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/)

That being said my suggestion would be to update to the JQM version 1.1.0 final.

Use this to get started

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set up a test app with nothing but your code here and added navigation. It is still unfortunately doing the same thing, showing the next page for a fraction of a second before showing the transition. Could it be my navigation? I've seen other apps that don't have this issue. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/2406606

Comment: So, a little more on this. It appears that if I take out the slide transition and use the default fade (or any other trans) on the nav, my problem ceases. It seams to be tied to the slide nav. I'm also wondering if this is partly a phonegap issue as well. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you testing on an Android device? Tell me more about what platforms you are targeting. Part of the problem is how well the device supports 3d transforms.

Comment: I suggest you learn to live with a simple fade transition. It does not require support for 3d transforms.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to just stick with a default of no transition. Even the fade transition was a bit messed up as it blinked when it ran the transition. JQM is really close to what I need but it is so buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fix](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html):

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this bit before but it doesn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with using the same ID. Check to make sure your ID is different on each of your pages. That's what it sounds like to me

Comment: I'm assuming you mean page id's? I checked and they are all different. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing with this problem several times, and just when I was going to suicide, found that the problem was in some custom CSS classes, and I've fixed it!
For example, I had in my  body declaration:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Remove margin, and voilá! Something was fixed!
In other app, I found at a custom wrapper class declaration:

```
.wrapper{
    <blabla>
    position:absolute;
    <blabla>
}
```

Of course, this "Absolute" forces the engine to render the page at the absolute position, and then, initiates the transition.

So, how to fix your issue?

I recommend that you remark all your .css file, and start testing class by class, try the transition, and when the transition fails, there you have the "disturbing" class.

Try it, and let us know if it fixes the issues to you!